# How to parse the body result from alexa custom skill to JSON

Tags: ios, swift, alexa-skills-kit

I was able to set up the Alexa custom skill and call it from my IOS app. When I test the skill in the Alexa console simulator, I can see the JSON output and I want to get it from my IOS app, however, I'm having a problem with how to parse it. My IOS code is working fine as I can hear the text response from my custom skill.

Here's the sample JSON output I want to get/parse

```
    {
        "body": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "response": {
                "outputSpeech": {
                    "type": "SSML",
                    "ssml": "<speak>Hello this is a custom skill</speak>"
                },
                "type": "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
            },
            "sessionAttributes": {},
            "userAgent": "ask-node/2.9.0 Node/v10.23.1 sample/hello-world/v1.2"
        }
    }
```

Here's the code for posting the recording

```
func postRecording(authToken:String, jsonData:String, audioData: Data) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: EVENTS_ENDPOINT)!)
        //request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
        request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
        request.timeoutInterval = 60
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Bearer \(authToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let boundry = NSUUID().uuidString
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundry)"
        
        request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        var bodyData = Data()
        
        bodyData.append("--\(boundry)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        bodyData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"metadata\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        bodyData.append("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        bodyData.append(jsonData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        bodyData.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        
        bodyData.append("--\(boundry)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        bodyData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        bodyData.append("Content-Type: audio/L16; rate=16000; channels=1\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        bodyData.append(audioData)
        bodyData.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        
        bodyData.append("--\(boundry)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        
        session.uploadTask(with: request, from: bodyData, completionHandler: { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Send audio error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            } else {
                let res = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode <= 299) {
                    if let contentTypeHeader = res.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] {
                        let boundary = self.extractBoundary(contentTypeHeader: contentTypeHeader as! String)
                        let directives = self.extractDirectives(data: data!, boundary: boundary)
                        self.directiveHandler?(directives)
                    } else {
                        print("Content type in response is empty")
                    }
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }

func extractDirectives(data: Data, boundary: String) -> [DirectiveData] {
        var directives = [DirectiveData]()
        
        let innerBoundry = "--\(boundary)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let endBoundry = "--\(boundary)--".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let contentTypeApplicationJson = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let contentTypeAudio = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let headerEnd = "\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        
        var startIndex = 0
        while (true) {
            let firstAppearance = data.range(of: innerBoundry, in: startIndex..<(data.count))
            if (firstAppearance == nil) {
                break
            }
            var secondAppearance = data.range(of: innerBoundry, in: (firstAppearance?.upperBound)!..<(data.count))
            if (secondAppearance == nil) {
                secondAppearance = data.range(of: endBoundry, in: (firstAppearance?.upperBound)!..<(data.count))
                if (secondAppearance == nil) {
                    break
                }
            } else {
                startIndex = (secondAppearance?.lowerBound)!
            }
            let subdata = data.subdata(in: (firstAppearance?.upperBound)!..<(secondAppearance?.lowerBound)!)
            var contentType = subdata.range(of: contentTypeApplicationJson)
            if (contentType != nil) {
                let headerRange = subdata.range(of: headerEnd)
                var directiveData = String(data: subdata.subdata(in: (headerRange?.upperBound)!..<subdata.count), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "Directive data is not String"
                directiveData = directiveData.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: "")
                directives.append(DirectiveData(contentType: "application/json", data: directiveData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!))
                print("Directive: \(directiveData)")
            }
            contentType = subdata.range(of: contentTypeAudio)
            if (contentType != nil) {
                let headerRange = subdata.range(of: headerEnd)
                let audioData = subdata.subdata(in: (headerRange?.upperBound)!..<subdata.count)
                directives.append(DirectiveData(contentType: "application/octet-stream", data: audioData))
                print("Audio data")
            }
        }
        return directives
    }
```

My current code only returns this sample response

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "SpeechSynthesizer",
        "name": "Speak",
        "messageId": "35601dca-413f-4788-93ed-305e04328d0e",
        "dialogRequestId": "db933fd9-3766-407d-99f6-2b33d9c814e6",
        "keys": {
            "isBlocking": true,
            "channel": "audio"
        }
    },
    "payload": {
        "format": "AUDIO_MPEG",
        "token": "amzn1.as-ct.v1.ThirdPartySdkSpeechlet#ACRI#ValidatedSpeakDirective_amzn1.ask.skill.5718d3ec-b56a-4a5a-bd61-fdd4ab501fc2_ca3ae40b-52cd-4be9-b831-98e975a57e5a_VoiceInitiated#ACRI#[[ENCRYPTED_WITH_AlexaServiceKeyMasterUtil]]AAAAAAAAAAAHT6zrrzQh3EDQVwUGrjOpUAAAAAAAAACFZJ/VU0i9/OCY89UvtcV9X0291NLF7L7nE4irlDAGaph7NlUpgq0Ps31s8OflwHh/9wr3vp5Py+Gz+2Lgd8N6fPXWxPHp8+E6R8sLiRh9Cg==",
     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this right, you won't get that response.

Looks like you have an AVS device posting audio to the Alexa voice service.

The audio you send is received by the service, converted into an intent and data, and sent to your skill.

The response you're looking for with the "speak" tags is sent by the ASK SDK from your skill to Alexa.

Alexa converts that into audio and sends the audio to your AVS client, but doesn't send a copy of the direct output from your skill command that produced it. You simply can't parse it out of the response.

Comment: Is it possible to customize the Alexa response(JSON) and have it send to my AVS client? @LetMyPeopleCode

Comment: Been a while since I worked with the AVS APIs, but check out this documentation page for the SpeechSynthesizer directive. If your app is getting that, then you may find the text content in the "caption" property... https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-voice-service/speechsynthesizer.html

Comment: I can access the SpeechSnythesize.Speak directive however I don't see the caption property. I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this issue. It's been days since I'm stuck with it. @LetMyPeopleCode

Comment: What's your use case. Why do you need this information and what are you going to do with it?

Comment: I want to play music(categorized in the genre) in my custom app using Alexa. I want to get the specific genre uttered by the user, for ex. user says, play 80's music. If I have this value as JSON response from Alexa then I can just play the music in my custom app programmatically. Is this the correct approach? @LetMyPeopleCode

Comment: I'm afraid anything I would suggest for AVS would be a hack that would get your AVS client or skill rejected. What you might want to explore is an API in developer preview (have to apply for access) called Alexa for Apps. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/response-api/alexa-for-apps.

I'll continue looking into whether there's a "good" way to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am now able to play music using the AudioPlayer interface. I used static stream URL only and now I'm planning to access my own API in lambda function to get my streams. Let me know if there's a problem with this implementation.